# String binary to Hex Java

Tags: java, string, binary, hex

i have code that looks like this

```
             public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string= "11011100010000010001000000000000";
   String string1= "00000000010000110000100000101100";

    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(string1,2)));

    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(string,2)));


}
```

the first string convert just fine but the second one has an error of  java.lang.NumberFormatException
dont know what the problem is

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should "check" the answer that you accept. This will not only mark the question as closed but will also give a bonus reputation to the person who helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the most significant bit of a 32-character binary number is set to `1`, the resultant value exceeds the range of positive numbers supported by `int`, and can no longer be interpreted as a valid integer number. This causes the exception according to the documentation:

An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:

> - The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
> - The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than Character.MAX_RADIX.
> - Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') provided that the string is longer than length 1.
> - **The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.** (emphasis is mine)

In order to enter this negative binary value, use `-` sign in front of your number, and convert the remaining bits to 2-s complement representation.

If you need numbers that are longer than 32 bits, or if you would like the value to continue being interpreted as a positive number, you would need to switch to the 64-bit integer data type.

Comment: +1, but `parseInt` and its opposite have nothing to do with "real binary", they work on base-2 number system. There is no significant bit, nor is the fact that the string is 32 characters long treated any differently than any other amount. So adding a `-` in front of this number, will just be equivalent of `-3695251456` in base-10 and will cause the same exception.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(string,2))
```

(edited from parsLong to parseLong)

Comment: The explanation makes no sense though. Starting with `0` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: im trying to convert it to a hex value with a specified length needed

Comment: Crashes for me with long bit values (96 bit to hex). For that, @Yanick Rochon's one does the trick. Appart from that, your provided code is mistyped (should be `parseLong`).

Answer (score 3):

For what's worth, you can also use the `BigInteger` class :

```
String string  = "11011100010000010001000000000000";
String string1 = "00000000010000110000100000101100";

System.out.println(new BigInteger(string1, 2).toString(16));
System.out.println(new BigInteger(string, 2).toString(16));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Long` instead of `Integer`, (`Long.parseLong` and `Long.toHexString` methods).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse to integer, the range should be

`10000000000000000000000000000000` to `01111111111111111111111111111111`