# Converting integer list containing binary to hex

Tags: java, binary, hex

I have a integer list which contains some binary values

```
List<Integer> binary = new ArrayList();
for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    bin[i] = pText[i] ^ ivKey[i]; //some binary value is calculated
    binary.add(bin[i]); //the binary list gets updated here
}

for (int i=0; i<myCipher2.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.print(binary.get(i)); //this prints the appended binary as shown in the output
}
```

The list when printed gives the following:

> 000001010100001110011101

Each 8 bits refers to a hex so the output I want when converted should give me the following

> 05 43 9d

How can I break the list into 8 bits and convert those 8 bits into hex?

Comment: by gooooooooogling it :)

Comment: You think I may not have tried that method Kick Buttowski?

Comment: Please explain _which contains some binary values_. Printing an `ArrayList` will never give that output. Please give a reproducible example.

Comment: @vbenthu look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677121/string-binary-to-hex-java

Comment: Your list contains `Integer` values, not bits nor bytes. An `int` is represented using 4 bytes. Please explain how you expect each `Integer` (or its corresponding `int`) to be printed in hex. Have you looked at `Integer.toString(int, int)`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. To be honest Im just a newbie and I dont know how to make use of bit and bytes. All i was doing was appending and int value to the list. Now the list is long and I want to break it into 8 bits to calculate hex

Comment: Ok, you should review some of the concepts. Bits is not something you convert to hex. hex is just a representation, just like binary and decimal.

Comment: @vbenthu I took my googling advice back :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you should not declare generic objects with raw types, add a type to your `ArrayList`:

```
List<Integer> binary = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Since it isn't directly related to your question, you can [**read why you should do this here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Now, so since your list holds individual binary digits, what you can do is use a `StringBuilder` to build 8-bit binary strings from it.  You can also use a `StringBuilder` to build the converted hex value. Each time you build this 8-bit string, you convert it to it to hex (actually first to decimal and then to hex) and append it to the `StringBuilder` then builds the hex string.

Here is the code:

```
// ... your program

StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder eightBits = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < binary.size(); i += 8) {                 
    for(int j = i; j < (i + 8) && j < binary.size(); j++) { // read next 8 bits or whatever bits are remaining
        eightBits.append(binary.get(j)); // build 8 bit value
    }
    int decimal = Integer.parseInt(eightBits.toString(), 2); // get decimal value
    hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(decimal) + " "); // add hex value to the hex string and a space for readability 
    eightBits.setLength(0); // reset so we can append the new 8 bits
}
System.out.println(hexString.toString()); // prints "5 43 9d" for the value you gave
```

**Note:** this program is a continuation of your program

Comment: the whole issue is how to read 8 characters at time from the list or String?

Comment: @KickButtowski Yes, that is the main issue here

Comment: @KickButtowski well, I just tried to answer his question, not completely redo his program. I edited again to fit his code and the program does what he needs. Hopefully, this is to everybody's satisfaction :)

Comment: @nem so many times, I get voted down because I represent no optimized solutions, and their justification was since the op did not said what way, you MUST represent the best way you can. I did not vote you down as you see, yet it is logical to ask why we should learn this when even you claim it is not a right and good way?

Comment: @KickButtowski i completely understand and agree with you. However, **vbenthu** is just messing around and learning, his whole approach seems very efficient, but he didn't show his full code for me to determine how to optimize it nor he asked advice on how to do that. I specifically targeted to answer his direct question which is how to convert 8 individual binary digits from a list into a hex value. Do you think I shouldn't do this and delete my answer? There can be a whole discussion made on whats and hows to approach solving this problem, I just wanted to help him solve it his way...

Comment: @nem thank you nem for your effort, time and explanation. Your code works just fine. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a binary string and convert it to decimal and then to hex:

```
    int[] arr = {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1};
    int i = 0;
    while (i < arr.length) {
        String res = "";
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            res += arr[i];
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(res, 2)));
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
5
43
9d
```

Comment: I thought about this way, but i does not change like 0-8,9-17,...?

Comment: @KickButtowski You probably meant 0-7, 8-15, 16-23... And I'm not sure I understood your question.

Answer (score 1):

So, here's my take on it...

Basically, this uses `List#subList` to create a sub list of the main binary array.  Each sublist contains up to 8 values...

```
int length = Math.min(8, bits.size());
List<Integer> byteList = bits.subList(0, length);
```

I then reverse this list, you easily reverse the `for-loop` order, this just seem simpler to me...

```
Collections.reverse(byteList);
```

Then I use a simple `for-loop` to loop through the sub list.  For each bit that is `1`, I simply add it's binary equivalent (`Math.pow(2, index)`) to the resulting value

```
for (int index = 0; index < byteList.size(); index++) {
    int bit = byteList.get(index);
    if (bit == 1) {
        int pos = (int)Math.pow(2, index);
        value += pos;
    }
}
```

Then I remove the first n values the master list and continue until there is nothing left...

This will then print...

```
Word = 00000101 = 5; 0x05
Word = 01000011 = 67; 0x43
Word = 10011101 = 157; 0x9d
```

Runnable example...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> bits = new ArrayList<Integer>(25);
        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(1);
        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(1);

        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(1);
        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(1);
        bits.add(1);

        bits.add(1);
        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(1);
        bits.add(1);
        bits.add(1);
        bits.add(0);
        bits.add(1);

        System.out.println();

        while (bits.size() > 0) {

            int length = Math.min(8, bits.size());
            List<Integer> byteList = bits.subList(0, length);
            Collections.reverse(byteList);
            int value = 0;
            StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder(8);
            for (int index = 0; index < byteList.size(); index++) {
                int bit = byteList.get(index);
                if (bit == 1) {
                    int pos = (int)Math.pow(2, index);
                    value += pos;
                }
                binary.insert(0, bit);
            }

            System.out.println("Word = " + binary + " = " + value + "; 0x" + pad(2, Integer.toHexString(value)));

            int size = Math.max(0, bits.size());
            bits = bits.subList(length, size);

        }
    }

    public static String pad(int length, String value) {
        StringBuilder zeros = new StringBuilder(value);
        while (zeros.length() < length) {
            zeros.insert(0, "0");
        }
        return zeros.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: @KickButtowski Don't know if it's any better or worse than the other approaches, was hoping to do some bit masking, but that was proving to implode my head...ah, takes me back to my days at high school...:P

Comment: u r a hoot sir. I'll study ur way for sure . alsafin gave the good answer too. thank u again