# JLabel keyboad alternative

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

The first paragraph of the [JLabel API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) states:

*"A label does not react to input events. As a result, it cannot get the keyboard focus. A label can, however, display a keyboard alternative as a convenience for a nearby component that has a keyboard alternative but can't display it."*

I'm pretty sure I understand the concept of not being able to gain focus for keyboard events. What I'm not sure about is what it means when it says "A label can display a keyboard alternative as a convenience for a nearby component that has a keyboard alternative but can't display it".

What is a **keyboard alternative**? Why wouldn't a *nearby component be able to display it*? How does a label display a keyboard alternative for a near-by component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it means is, with a combination of [`JLabel#setDisplayedMnemonic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setDisplayedMnemonic(char)) and [`JLabel#setLabelFor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setLabelFor(java.awt.Component)) you can configure the label to display a short cut key to the user that when activiated, with transfer focus to the associated component.

The mnemonic is a single character within the text of the label, which when the activation key is held down (<kbd>Alt</kbd> on windows), will allow the user to transfer focus to the associated field.

For example, if you had a label with the text `First name:`, you could set the `mnemonic` to `F`, which would allow the user to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to focus the associated field.

Under windows, when you hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, it will display an underscore character under the mnemonic character.  So Look and Feels will always display this underscore and some may highlight the fact in other ways

Comment: can you solve this too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007835/converting-integer-list-containing-binary-to-hex

Answer (score 1):

> How does a label display a keyboard alternative for a near-by component?

Say you have a label "First Name" followed by a text field. You can use:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
JLabel label = new JLabel("First Name");
label.setLabelFor( textField );
label.setDisplayedMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
```

Now when the user uses `Alt-F` focus will be placed on the related text field.